# show opencv in kivymd screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivymd

I am working on drowsiness detection so I need to use OpenCV but i am having a problem showing the webcam stream on kivymd GUI, and I am using multiple screens and I need it to show in a certain one.
here the code I am using currently

```
class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

Comment: I am working on this too. Bookmarking and will get back to you. Did you figure it out?

Comment: unfortunately no, but I will share the answer if I find it

Comment: I have a hacky version for a raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

**your code works for me**

just add these **imports**:

```
from kivymd.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
```

Comment: Have anyone find solutions to this

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding a button in one of the screen class inside the .kv file
And create a function which was binded to the button.
The func convert the image texture of kivy into opencv texture!

Hope you understand this

Comment: Can you please share an example?